# PyTorch: Comparing predicted label and target label to compute accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, torch, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to implement [this](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#test-the-network-on-the-test-data) loop to get the accuracy of my PyTorch CNN (The complete code of it is [here](https://github.com/philippHRO/Customized_Dataloader_two/blob/master/multi_label_classifier_for2classes.py))
My version of the loop is so far:

```
correct = 0
    test_total = 0
    for itera, testdata2 in enumerate(test_loader, 0):
        test_images2, test_labels2 = testdata2
        if use_gpu:
            test_images2 = Variable(test_images2.cuda())
        else:
            test_images2 = Variable(test_images2)
        outputs = model(test_images2)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)       
        test_total += test_labels2.size(0)      
        test_labels2 = test_labels2.type_as(predicted)
        correct += (predicted == test_labels2[0]).sum()    
    print('Accuracy of the network on all the test images: %d %%' % (
        100 * correct / test_total))
```

If I run it like this, I get:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:/python_code/Customized-DataLoader-master_two/multi_label_classifier_for2classes.py",
> line 186, in <module>
>     main()   File "c:/python_code/Customized-DataLoader-master_two/multi_label_classifier_for2classes.py",
> line 177, in main
>     correct += (predicted == test_labels2[0]).sum()   File "C:\anaconda\envs\pytorch_cuda\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py",
> line 360, in __eq__
>     return self.eq(other) RuntimeError: invalid argument 3: sizes do not match at
> c:\anaconda2\conda-bld\pytorch_1519501749874\work\torch\lib\thc\generated\../THCTensorMathCompareT.cuh:65
```

I used `test_labels2 = test_labels2.type_as(predicted)` to have both tensors as LongTensors, which seems to work fine to avert the "Expected this...but got..." errors. They look like this now:

```
test_labels2 after conversion:
 0  1
 1  0
 1  0
[torch.cuda.LongTensor of size 3x2 (GPU 0)]

predicted:
 1
 1
 1
[torch.cuda.LongTensor of size 3 (GPU 0)]
```

I supppose the problem now is, that `test_labels2[0]` is returning a row but not the column.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: can you elaborate what `test_labels` and `predicted` represent (what they mean)? the error seems obvious because: in `(predicted == test_labels2[0])` - `test_labels2[0]` is of size 2 and `predicted` is of size 3.

Comment: `predicted` are the predicted classes of images that were propagated through the neural net. `test_labels` are the true labels from the training data. Both have three rows, because in this case batch_size of the dataloader is set to 3.
Indeed, I think I only need to know, how to index certain columns in a TorchLongTensor, so I can compare predicted and test_labels. How do i do that?

Comment: You can simply use indexing as in numpy: `test_labels2[:, 0]` for example will give you the first column. Did this fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think I need to take some numpy lessons :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing in `pytorch` works mostly like indexing in `numpy`. To index all rows of a certain column `j` use:

```
tensor[:, j]
```

Alternatively, the [select](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.select) function from pytorch can be used.